# How to fit a product of linear expressions

Tags: regression

How can I fit expressions of type $y = (a + bx_1)(c + dx_2)$ using regression?

Answer (score 5):

You can reformulate your expression like this:
$$
y = ac + adx_2 + cbx_1 + bdx_1x_2
$$

Then, you can give new names as follows:

$$
ac = m\\
ad = n\\
cb = p\\
bd = q\\
x_2 = z_1\\
x_1 = z_2\\
x_1 x_2 = z_3\\
$$

Obtaining this expression:
$$
y = m + nz_1 + pz_2 + q z_3
$$

Now you can fit that expression with the $z_i$ data created from the $x_i$ data.

Once you have values for $m, n, p, q$, you can solve the equations to find the values of a, b, c, d. You can use Wolfram Alpha for that (e. [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+a*c%3Dm%2C+a*d%3Dn%2C+c*b%3Dp%2C+b*d%3Dq+for+a%2C+b%2C+c%2C+d)).

Comment: But, after the fit, if for example, we get $m = 1$, $n = 2$, $p = 2$ and $q = 1$, then this expression is equivalent to $(x_1 + 2)(x_2 + 2) - 3$. But I don't want to have the intercept \(3\).

Comment: The fact that the reformulated equation I proposed has more solutions than the original one does not mean that these solutions can happen with data that has been derived from the original formulation. The values of $m, n, p, q$ that you proposed should not happen with data that is compatible with $y=(a + b x_1)(c+ d x_2)$.